# como converter um request.Parameter de string para inteiro

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, request

Em um programa que tenho que fazer me surgiu essa dificuldade

```
Familia.setSalariodoPai(request.getParameter("salariodoPai"));
```

porem esse request está retornando um String sendo que eu precisaria do Integer

.obs esse trecho esta em um doGet do servlet

Comment: minha pergunta me parece mais completa que a comentada

Comment: Mas a resposta que você precisa está lá. Você testou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa converter para Integer.

```
Familia.setSalariodoPai(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("salariodoPai")));
```

Existem vários tópicos explicando isso, pesquise antes de postar :)